# Discrepancy in Widths of a Range and a Paragraph Element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, range

I’m working on a feature in a web application that mimics the text selection behavior in Microsoft Office Word. Specifically, when you select text across two paragraphs in Word, the area between the two paragraphs starts to shade gray. I’m trying to replicate this behavior in a web environment using JavaScript and CSS.

To accomplish this I first try to get the range that spans the last line of the first paragraph. I then try to get the width of the `range` using `range.getBoundingClientRect().width`.

Next, I set the width of a paragraph (`<p id="dummy">`), placed between the two `<p>` tags and acts as a shading element, to be the same as the width of the `range`:

```
let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
let width = range.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let dummy = document.getElementById('dummy');
dummy.style.width = width + 'px';
dummy.style.backgroundColor = '#C0C0C0';
```

However, I’ve noticed that the width of the dummy paragraph displayed on the screen is occasionally slightly different from the width of the range, even though I’m setting them to be the same.

I understand that both the range and the dummy element widths are set in CSS pixels, and when they are translated to actual pixel values by the engine, they ought to lead to the same value after rounding. However, this is not what I’m observing.

By the way, I do not see this behavior when testing the code in Firefox. This problem occurs when I test the code in Chrome and Edge browsers.

Could anyone explain why this discrepancy might be occurring? Are there any other methods to get the width of a range that might give more consistent results with the paragraph width?

**Summary**

I am getting a range from a selection, measuring its width using `getBoundingClientRect()`, and then setting the width of a paragraph element (dummy) to match. However, I am noticing that the rendered width of the dummy element on the screen is sometimes slightly different from the width of the range. The picture below shows the offset on the right edge:

[image]

The `range` is associated with the text selected in the image. The dummy `<p>` tag is right below the `<p>` tag that contains the text. The dummy `<p>` tag is supposed to take the same width as the `range`'s width, but a slight misalignment is observed on the right edge. I am not able to explain why this sort of behavior is happening.

Comment: Can you describe the discrepancy?

Comment: I edited my post, see if it does answer your doubt?